# Does golang foment no file structure?

Tags: go

I've been looking into golang in order to build a web app, I like the language and everything, but I'm having trouble wrapping my head around the concept of structure in golang. It seems it pretty much forces me to have no file structure, no folders, no division, no separation of concerns. Is there any way to organize the .go files in a way that I'm not seeing? So far file structuring has been a headache and it's the only bad experience I've had with the language. Thank you!

Comment: did you look at : https://golang.org/doc/code.html ?

Comment: yes I did, from what I gather if I would use an MVC pattern I would have to create a package for a controller and models right? But arent packages supposed to be for use in multiple systems?

Comment: https://github.com/gernest/utron might be a nice exemple

Comment: thanks, I'll give it a look. An issue I was having yesterday was that I managed to build my own small framework and ran perfectly with go run main.go but not while deploying to google cloud platform or testing with dev_appserver.py so I'm rebuilding it all over again

Answer (score 2):

You are partially right. Go does not enforce anything regarding file and package structure, except that it forbids circular dependencies. IMHO, this is a good thing, since you have freedom to choose what best suites you.

However, it puts burden on you to decide what is the best. I have tried few approaches and depending on what I am doing (e.g. library, command line tool, service) I believe different approaches are best.

If you are creating only command line tool, let root package (root of your repository) be `main`. If it is small tool, that is all you need. It might happen that you command line tool grows, so you might want to separate some stuff to their own that can, but does not have to be, in same repository.

If you are creating library, do the same, except that package name will be name of your library, not `main`.

If you need combination (something that is useful both as the library and command line tool), I would go with putting library code (everything public for the library) in VCS root, with potential sub-packages and `cmd/toolname` for your binary.

When it comes to web services, I found it is most practical to follow [these](https://medium.com/@benbjohnson/standard-package-layout-7cdbc8391fc1) guidelines. It is best to read entire blog post, but in short - define your domain in VCS root, create `cmd/app` (or multiple) as command line entry point and create one package per dependency (e.g. memcache, database, http, etc). Your sub-packages never depend on each other explicitly, they only share domain definitions from root. It takes some getting used to and I am still adapting it to my use case, but so far it looks promising.

Comment: that's an interesting way of putting it, I was going with a whole other approach by having my handlers in an independent package that share structs and database services and just import that into my main

Answer (score 1):

As @del-boy said it depends on what you want to do, I went over this problem multiple times but what suited me more when developing a golang web app is to divide your packages by dependencies

```
- myproject 
-- cmd 
--- main.go
-- http
--- http.go
-- postgres
--- postgres.go
-- mongodb
--- mongodb.go
myproject.go
```

**myproject.go** will contain the **Interfaces** and **Structs** that contain the main domain or business models

For example you can have inside **myproject.go**

```
type User struct {
MongoID    bson.ObjectId `bson:"_id,omitempty"`
PostgresID string
Username       string 
}
```

and an Interface like this

```
type UserService interface { 
GetUser(username string) (*User, error)
}
```

Now in your **http** package you will handle exposing your api endpoints

```
 //Handler represents an HTTP API interface for our app.
type Handler struct {
    Router         *chi.Mux // you can use whatever router you like
    UserService    myproject.UserService
}

func (h *Handler) ServeHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, r *Request){
//this just a wrapper for the Router ServeHTTP
h.Router.ServeHTTP(w,r)
}

func (h *Handler) someHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *Request){
//get the username from the request
// 
user := h.UserService.GetUser(username)
}
```

in your postgres.go you can have a **struct** that implements **UserService**

```
type PostgresUserService struct {
DB *sql.DB
}
```

and then you implement the service

```
func (s *PostgresUserService) GetUser(username string) {
//implement the method
}
```

and the same thing can be done with mongodb

```
type MongoUserService struct {
Session *mgo.Session
}

func (s *MongoUserService) GetUser(username string) {
    //implement the method
    }
```

Now in your cmd/main.go you can have something like this

```
func main(){
postgresDB, err := postgres.Connect()
mongoSession, err := mongo.Connect()

postgresService := postgres.PostgresUserService{DB: postgresDB}
mongoService := mongo.MongoUserService{Session: mongoSession}

//then pass your services to your http handler
// based on the underlying service your api will act based on the underlying service you passed 
myHandler := http.Handler{}
myHandler.UserService = postgresService


}
```

assuming you changed your underlying store you only have to change it in here and you will not change anything

This design is heavily inspired from this [blog](https://medium.com/@benbjohnson/standard-package-layout-7cdbc8391fc1), I hope you find it helpful

Comment: your structure actually gave me an idea since right now I'm having issues with long codes for simple things, connecting, querying, storying into a slice and sending that to the template in a single file that ALSO contains my structs is playing with my ocd, I'm trying to find a nice way to separate those into either a structs package (models for example) or using a service to call the database and have that handle the querying and storage into a slice

Comment: I suggest you put these models in the root of the project together with the interface definition, and for each package that needs to provide a certain service it should implement it (Satisfies the interface to be precise)